# Maching ids doesn't return true when compared

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make some comprobations on my API (Node.js + Mongodb)

I want to check if the proposerId is equal to the eventOrganizer. To do so

I'm sending this on the body:

```
{
    "participantId": "6238a608170aff10d16ccd89",
    "proposerId": "62385d8caee17d13a1762b39", // this guy id is also an organizer
    "gender": "female",
    "groupId": "623aea21fcfad83bcf8d5bc4"
}
```

in my PATCH controller to add a user I have this verification:

```
exports.addParticipantToEvent = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Group Organizer constants
  const eventId = req.params.eventId;
  const groupId = req.body.groupId;
  const proposerId = req.body.proposerId; // it can be an admin adding someone to the participants list

  // Participant constants
  const participantId = req.body.participantId;
  const gender = req.body.gender;

  // EVENT
  // Does the event even exist?
  const eventData = await Event.findById(eventId);

  if (!eventData) {
    return res.status(406).json({
      code: 'EVENT_DOESNT_EXIST',
      message: 'The event is not valid.',
    });
  }

  console.log(eventData);

  // What kind of users can participate in this event?
  const allowedParticipants = eventData.allowedParticipants;

  // whos the event organizer?
  const eventOrganizer = eventData.organizer._id;

  console.log('Organizer: ' + eventOrganizer);
  console.log('Proposer: ' + proposerId);
  console.log('Result: ' + proposerId === eventOrganizer);

  try {
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'The participant can be added',
      participantId: participantId,
      gender: gender,
      allowedParticipants: allowedParticipants,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

I want to verify is the proposerId is an admin or an organizer of the event, so I console.log the eventData entirely and later I console log all the constants I want to verify and the result, it gives me false all the time.

Maybe I need to specify better something?

```
{
  location: { province: 'Barcelona' },
  _id: new ObjectId("634ffee75990124926431e6f"),
  title: 'Test open close 14',
  sport: new ObjectId("622ce6ca672c3d4447676705"),
  group: new ObjectId("623aea21fcfad83bcf8d5bc4"),
  organizer: new ObjectId("62385d8caee17d13a1762b39"),
  participants: [ new ObjectId("62385d8caee17d13a1762b39") ],
  replacements: [],
  invitations: [],
  when: 2022-10-09T13:43:02.999Z,
  open: true,
  costPerParticipant: 4.4,
  skill: 'novice',
  allowedGender: 'female',
  minParticipants: 2,
  maxParticipants: 5,
  visible: false,
  externalLink: 'https://www.komoot.es/tour/731122050?ref=wta',
  allowInvitations: true,
  allowReplacements: false,
  allowedParticipants: 'only-members',
  createdAt: 2022-10-19T13:43:03.006Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-10-19T13:43:03.006Z,
  __v: 0
}
Organizer: 62385d8caee17d13a1762b39
Proposer: 62385d8caee17d13a1762b39
false
```

As you can see, both Organizer and proposer are same id, yet I get false.

Comment: One is an object, the other one  a string. `console.log` implicitly calls `toString` so the output is the same. But `===` does a strict type comparison, is it only can return true if the types are equal. Try logging `typeof EventOrganizer` and `typeof proposerId` and you will see the difference

Answer (score 0):

After lurking some more, I have found that to validate mongos object ids with strings I need to use equals(). So now I have the solution.